# Import for mockito

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to put statement like

```
when(myDao.fetchTree(anyLong())).thenReturn(myTreeList);
```

and I have import

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.anyLong;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.thenReturn; //not importing
```

import for thenReturn is not mapping. Is this a version issue? I am using Mockito 1.8.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mockito's when returns an object of class OngoingStubbing.  This class has a method thenReturn(), and that's what gets called in your example code.  No additional import is needed.

```
when(myDao.fetchTree(anyLong())).thenReturn(myTreeList);
```

could be broken up as

```
OngoingStubbing thing = when(myDao.fetchTree(anyLong()));
thing.thenReturn(myTreeList);
```

You are just calling the `thenReturn` method of OngoingStubbing.

Comment: But STS is complaining with red underline.

Comment: Can't you simply delete the import line?

Comment: I already deleted it. Some other import I have are import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull; may be they are causing conflict

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;


import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Matchers;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

Comment: Try to recreate this in a minimal test file.  Basically, a class with a single test method with only what you need to reproduce the problem and nothing more.  Either the exercise will show you what needs to be fixed, or you can post that minimal file here and we can figure it out from that.

Answer (score 7):

It should be enough if you use:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
```

And remove the rest.

Comment: Normally I hate * imports, they make refactoring hard.  But for tests and importing test support like this?  go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Your question: *Is this a version issue?*
I'd say *NO, that is not a version issue.*

As suggested previously, you should

- create minimal test with this code in test

  ```
  when(myDao.fetchTree(anyLong())).thenReturn(myTreeList);
  ```
- run this code from command-line (not inside in STS or any IDE or something a like)

*Q:* Why run it from command-line and avoid using IDE-s etc?
*A:* Because sometimes code parsers and checkers and validators of your favorited IDE reports false positives about some corner-cases in code.